# What software/website can help me graph and get a diagram of an equation $f(x, y)$

Tags: computer-science, graphing-functions, online-resources

Below is the type of equation I want a digital diagram/graph for:

$f(x,y) = a_0x^3 + a_1x^2y + a_2xy^2 + a_3y^3 + a_4x^2 + a_5xy + a_6y^2 + a_7x + a_8y$

To clarify, $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7 ,a_8$ are known coefficients.

Please pardon my ignorance as I have just started.

Any help regarding how I can graph the solution (any website or software that can be useful) would be highly appreciated.

This is the actual polynomials with the coefficients substituted:
$$f(x, y) = -2.8553 x^3-10.431 x^2 y+0.28077 x^2-4.82487 x y^2+1.89407 x+\\+65.8761 x y-2.68436 y^3+14.7628 y^2-40.3066 y$$

These are the two new polynomials I need to graph:
$$ p(x, y) = -1.87019(x^3) -3.95625(x^2)(y) - 4.23593(x)(y^2) – 0.783805(y^3) + 4.39398(x^2) + 29.5375xy + 2.64509(y^2) – 4.64281x – 6.76092y $$

$$ q(x, y) = 8.53686(x^3) + 3.95625(x^2)(y) + 4.23593(x)(y^2) + 0.783805(y^3) – 34.394(x^2) – 29.5375xy – 2.64509(y^2) + 41.3095x + 6.76092y $$

Please teach me how to operate CalcPlot or GeoGebra because when I try to graph them myself, the scale is blown out of proportion and I do not know the right way to do it. Or if the graph could be shared by someone, I would really appreciate it as well.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: try here https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/

Comment: Free software GeoGebra (www.geogebra.org) should do it. Go to View, 3D Graphics. Go to input line at the bottom of the screen and type z = your polynomial.

Comment: @Raffaele thank you for the reply! the website seems great but I am having a small issue which I hope you could help me with. I don't understand what scale I should input for the axes because when I entered my polynomial, the resulting graph is very....well, botched. I can't view it clearly. I have edited my question and included the actual polynomial so could you please help me figure out a better scale?

Comment: I've got this. Looks decent https://imgur.com/OW9UxxK

Comment: yep thank you! I need help with graphing two similar polynomials, could you please help me with that? Again, when I am entering them in CalcPlot or GeoGebra, the scale is blown out of proportion and I do not know how to fix that. 

I have edited the question and included the two new polynomials. Also, I am trying to use MathJax and write the math properly this time hahah, thank you for editing my question earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Geogebra 3d is the easiest one, it is free and online. Otherwise you can use Matlab (or Octave) which can do much more than geogebra, but you have to learn their programming language